# Codeigniter 4: Login Multi User

Tags: php, authentication, codeigniter-4

I have a problem about login multi user in my sistem. The sistem login is not worked as a flowchart below (language is Indonesia):
[Flowchart Login Multi User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCFVf.jpg)

And the controller code is this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use App\Models\LoginModel;

/**
 * 
 */
class Login extends BaseController
{
    
    public function index()
    {
        helper(['form']);
        echo view('formlogin');
    }

    public function auth()
    {
        $session = session();
        $model = new LoginModel();
        $username = $this->request->getVar('username');
        $password = $this->request->getVar('password');

        $data = $model->where('username', $username)->get()->getRowArray();
        //$data = $model->get()->getResultArray();

        if ($data) {
            //$pass = $data['password'];
            $pass = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $verify = password_verify($password, $pass);
            

            if ($verify) {
                $session_data = [
                    'id_login' => $data['id_login'],
                    'username' => $data['username'],
                    'password' => $data['password'],
                    'level'    => $data['level'],
                    'logged_in' => TRUE
                ];
                $session->set($session_data);
                
                if ($level = 'adminsuper') {
                    return redirect()->to(base_url('/adminsuper'));
                }elseif ($level = 'admin') {
                    return redirect()->to(base_url('/admin'));
                }
                //return redirect()->to(base_url('/adminsuper'));
            }else{
                $session->setFlashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Username dan Password Salah</div>');

                return redirect()->to(base_url('/login'));
            }
        }else{
            $session->setFlashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Pengguna Tidak Terdaftar</div>');
            return redirect()->to(base_url('/login'));
        }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $session = session();
        $session->destroy();
        return redirect()->to(base_url('/login'));
    }
}
?>
```

What should I do, in order to be able to login multi user based on user level?
The level of admin are **adminsuper** and **admin**.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

this way log in log out is outdatae use jwt(jwt.io) its modern
way login and secure